# Didn’t find class “android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout” on path: DexPathList in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-constraintlayout

I have very simple xamarin classic app with following .axml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Hello World!"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and following .cs file

```
[Activity(Label = "sa", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);//error throws here
    }
}
```

I found next code for .gradle to enable constraint layout

```
dependencies {
              compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
           }
```

But, of course, it doesn't work in Xamarin.Android. I tried to install 
[Xamarin Android Constraint Layout 1.0.0-beta5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout/)

but it doesn't work for  Mono.Android 6.0.

How I can solve my issue? Any guesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need is to change mono framework version is android.csproj
        v7.0

Answer (score 1):

The class `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` is not making the dex list for some reason.

Some reasons might be:

- It's not installed
- It's being linked away
- It's not making the main dex list but rather only the secondary dex list.

Use Classy Shark to determine what's going on(https://github.com/google/android-classyshark). Ensure that your linker setting is set to `None` to ensure that the Mono linker is not removing it either.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently (today actually) and I have been able to solve by adding an exception to my [linker settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker)

```
<assembly fullname="Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout">
  <type fullname="*" />
</assembly>

<assembly fullname="Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout.Solver">
  <type fullname="*" />
</assembly>
```

Obviously the respective class has been linked away (as Jon Douglas suggested). By adding this exception you prevent the class being linked away.